# Type string does not conform to protocol sequence type with coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am just fetching the data from the `CoreData` and wants to print it into `tableView`
So I tried to put the data into `Mutable array` so that I can access the date through the `Mutable array` into `TableView`
But I am getting this error
Following is my code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    var desc_arr: [String] = []

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext



    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {




                if let desc = result.valueForKey("desc") as? String {

                    print(desc)

                    for i in desc{
                        desc_arr.append(i)
                    }

                }

                if let amt = result.valueForKey("amt") as? String{
                    print(amt)

                }




            }

        }

    } catch {

        print("Fetch Failed")
    }

    print(desc_arr)


}



}
```

Comment: Try to read Apple documentation about `String` type in swift. Basically, you can not enumerate `String` as character array in cycle https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if let desc = result.valueForKey("desc") as? String
```

try

```
if let desc = result.valueForKey("desc") as? AnyObject
```

Cheers!